# Will Ubuntu support a 1920x360 resolution? I cannot find a clear answer

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

I've searched throughout the web and various conversations on Reddit and Hard Forums and cannot find a solution to my problem.

**The short version of my question; will Ubuntu allow me to set a custom resolution of 1920 x 360?**

The long version of my question where I previously tried Windows 10 but am now willing to accept Ubuntu. (Which I like, it just isn't my daily driver.)

I have two displays running Windows 10.

1. Acer B346C running at 2560 x 1080 on HDMI which works perfectly.
2. Bluefin 24" with a native resolution of 1920 x 360 on HDMI (it is 24" diagonal, but 5" in height), however, Windows does not offer me a 1920 x 360 resolution choice. There does not seem to be a specific driver for this display, and Windows does not recognize the make or model. These monitors **CAN** be daisy chained, but they don't seem to **NEED** to.

Additionally, when I go into the adapter properties, and then display properties, and "show all modes", that resolution isn't offered either.

I have dual Radeon R7 360s. However, when I attempt to create a custom resolution for display #2, the most recent version of AMD Catalyst software says "the custom resolution settings are not compatible with this display".

I've used CRU (custom resolution utility) found on a site about testing monitors. I'm being purposely vague about this site as I don't want my question removed for plugging a specific website.

My end goal with this display is to be the top of an arcade/MAME cabinet which changes its marquee based on the game being played.

Comment: You can try to read EDID of the 1920x360 monitor with `sudo get-edid | parse-edid` (both utils from `read-edid` package) or try `cvt 1920 360` and then create custom [modeline for Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xrandr#Adding_undetected_resolutions).

Comment: The display has no microSD card inserted, does it? The manual suggests it defaults to internal video playback mode if so. Or if the EDID information is not being sent, you will likely need to configure it manually, as stated..